# Trocar de section ao clicar no menu

Tags: javascript, html

Criei um menu da seguinte forma:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<nav class="vertical">
    <ul class="men clearfix1">
        <li><a href="#Tarefas Diárias">Tarefas Diárias</a>
            <!-- Nível 1 -->
            <!-- submenu -->
            <ul class="sub-men clearfix1">
                <li><a href="#1" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Gerais Quartos Ala A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv1">Gerais Quartos Ala B</a></li>
            </ul><!-- submenu -->
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

E aqui crio as `sections`:

```
<section id="1">
<div class="wrapper" id="minhaDiv" style="display:none" >
<?php 

$result_cursos = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.RegistolimpALAA ORDER BY dataregisto DESC";
$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);
...
?>  
</div>
</section>

<section id="2">
<div class="wrapper" id="minhaDiv1" style="display:none">
<?php 
$result_cursos1 = "SELECT * FROM centrodb.RegistolimpALAB ORDER BY dataregisto1 DESC";
$resultado_cursos1 = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos1);
...
?>  
</div>
</section>
```

E utilizo este JavaScript para mostrar e ocultar:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
  $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $(el).toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Mas pretendia que ao clicar num submenu mostre a `section` e quando clicar na segunda substitua a `section` anterior e não ter a necessidade de voltar a clicar na `section` anterior para a ocultar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só esconder as que estão visíveis, exceto a que você está mostrando/ocultando (toggle). Para isso use o seletor `:not` e `:visible`. O `:not` é para excluir do seletor a div alvo do evento e `:visible` para selecionar as divs que estão visíveis:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    el = $(this).data('element');
    $("section > div:not("+el+"):visible").hide();
    $(el).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<nav class="vertical">
    <ul class="men clearfix1">
        <li><a href="#Tarefas Diárias">Tarefas Diárias</a>
            <!-- Nível 1 -->
            <!-- submenu -->
            <ul class="sub-men clearfix1">
                <li><a href="#s1" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">Gerais Quartos Ala A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#s2" class="btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv1">Gerais Quartos Ala B</a></li>
            </ul><!-- submenu -->
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</div>

<section id="s1">
   <div class="wrapper" id="minhaDiv" style="display:none" >
      minhaDiv
   </div>
</section>

<section id="s2">
   <div class="wrapper" id="minhaDiv1" style="display:none">
      minhaDiv1
   </div>
</section>
```

> Agora, não use `id` com apenas um número (`id="1"`, `id="2"` etc.). [É
>   recomendado](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) que uma `id` inicie com uma letra. Por isso eu fiz uma alteração nas suas id's, adicionando um `s` (`id="s1"`, `id="s2"`).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90815/room-for-iniciante-and-sam